# API Gateway method integrates with lambda function but lambda function claims it has no triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that I'd like to trigger via HTTP request.

When I click `add trigger` to a lambda function, I get an API Gateway API set up with:

```
 method: ANY
```

Great.  Now, when viewing this lambda function, I see a trigger has been configured.

However, I would like to restrict the trigger to only allow `POST` requests.

So I deleted the API Gateway method `ANY`, and created a new method `POST`, under the same resource, using an integration type of `Lambda Function`.  I select my region, and sure enough, my existing lambda function is autocompleted.

However, when I view the `triggers` tab on the lambda function itself, it shows that there are no triggers.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had the same exact issue. Lambda function gets triggered with POST method nonetheless. I assumed it must be a GUI issue and the trigger won't appear in the `Triggers` tab unless the method was ANY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need flexible control of the API, I would suggest to use the API Gateway console to mange your API. Lambda triggers should only be used for simple use-cases - API methods configured through API Gateway will not show up in the Lambda triggers list.